# MySQL LEFT JOIN AND ORDER BY ERROR?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on some code and I came across some problems.

I have 2 tables "Table1" and "Table2" and I wanna combine both of them (`LEFT JOIN`). When I do everything works fine. But when I add `ORDER BY` at the end my website stops working for a few minutes.

The code:

```
SELECT table1.id, table2.id 
FROM table1 
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id 
ORDER BY table1.name 
LIMIT 0, 20
```

for some reason this code crashes the server.
any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How many rows in the database and how many would be returned if you removed the LIMIT?

Comment: Does this produce an error, or just a lag in the execution?

Comment: Is your foreign key in table 2 really `table2.id`? Or is this a brain fade

Comment: Are you getting any error from Mysql in your logs ?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Table1 has 32465 rows and Table2  has 6600 rows

Comment: I think my second comment _Is your foreign key in table 2 really table2.id? Or is this a brain fade_ Is probably more relevant

Comment: @RiggsFolly No table2.id is not the foreign key in table 2 but i have no duplicates in this column. Could this be the problem ?

Comment: Yes it could... If its not the foreign key then why are you joining on it

Comment: @RiggsFolly Ok it worked! I just ALTER TABLE the table2.id into UNIQUE and now i have no ORDER BY problems! Thank you for your help.